# CSS3 Border Radius

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/ZacharyKearns/pen/pgzRmP?editors=010

I am making a calculator with with js and css and the main div that holds the calculator body has rounded edges

```
#calc {
  background-color: #4CADEC;
  border-radius: 3%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 200px 300px 400px 225px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

I am trying to overlay the main body with a different background color for the screen part of the calculator

```
#top {
  background-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 15% 15% 0% 0%;
}
```

The problem is that because the top element is smaller the corners curve at a shallower angle than the calc div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply use absolute units?

```
#calc {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#top {
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXrPJE?editors=010